# How i can use variable present in python program inside the execute command function of linux

Tags: python, linux, ssh, paramiko

```
import paramiko
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.WarningPolicy())
client.connect('example.com',22,'XXXXX','XXXX')
a=input ("enter the file path")
stdin,stdout,stderr=client.exec_command('cd a && pwd')
```

I want to pass the variable 'a' to the exec_command .. 
I am trying to get the file path from the user and i am storing it in a variable a, i want to know how i can pass the variable a to the Cd command under exec_command function

Answer (score 1):

Since there can be some security flaws by code injection, you must not format user input directly into shell commands.

Here you can use environment variables:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=client.exec_command('cd "$a" && pwd', environment={'a': a})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try constructing the command from the variable?

```
stdin,stdout,stderr=client.exec_command('cd ' + str(a) + '&& pwd')
```

Comment: thnks .. Let me try that

Comment: This has the potential to be incredibly dangerous.